# SqlDependency dependency_OnChange Info "Query"

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

I have a very frustrating problem.  My .net 4 app has been successfully using the `SqlDependency` object for some time to receive INSERT or UPDATE notifications from SQL server.

However the database it receives notifications from has just been updated (it is the back end  to a 3rd party app so I don't know what the update entailed) and now when I restart my `SqlDependency` app it does not behave properly.  During the `StartSQLDependency()` method this line triggers the `dependency_OnChange` event:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_SqlCommand))
    adapter.Fill(_datatable);
```

With `SqlNotificationEventArgs`:

```
e.Info "Query"
e.Source "Statement"
e.Type "Subscribe"
```

Previously I had only seen:

```
e.Info "Update" or "Insert"
e.Source "Data"
e.Type "Change"
```

Can anyone please suggest what my have changed in the database to cause this?

Comment: What commands are you subscribing to?

Comment: Where do you declare your SqlDependency in your code? For example, if I wanted to subscribe to a certain table in a database, I'd instantiate a SqlDependency object with whatever SQL command I want to monitor. SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command); 
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(this, OnChange); then the "command" argument might be something like: SELECT [Column name]  FROM [dbo].[table] So whenever a change happens to my column in my table, it fires the OnChange event

Comment: _command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(_command);
            dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;

Comment: What's the "_command" command string?

Comment: 'select incidentid, incidentnumber, name, reportedbycustomercontactid, ProjectId, AssignedToId, workflowstepid from dbo.incidents where IncidentId > @IncidentId order by 1 desc'  As I mentioned, this query works fine with the pre-updated db.

Comment: Yeah I know, but your SqlDependency should only fire for the commands that you tell it to fire for, so I was trying to see the code. In the meantime, in your OnChange method, I would run a conditional check on e.Info and only do something if the property is "Update" or "Insert", if that's what you want. Some pseudo code: if(e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert) { // do stuff}

Comment: I would also have a look at this article, to make sure you're adhering to all the requirements for a notification. You might be getting unexpected behavior because of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: did you get it figured out?

Comment: No - I'm thinking that because the Type value in the args is Subscribe (when I'm only interested in Change) there must be something I need to unsubscribe from...

Comment: Precisely. But if you're sure the code contains no other dependency subscriptions, then I doubt OnChange is firing out of thin air. There's either a problem with the database notification service, or you're subscribing somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but for future generations...

In trying to research SqlDependency triggers, I came across a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events) that says that an event with those parameters indicates a bad query being used for the notifications (about halfway down the article).

Microsoft has [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx) about the supported notification statements (for SQL Server 2008) and how to properly build them to avoid this error event.